# Change the sorting direction of a single category in Magento 1.12

Tags: magento, sorting

I have an Magento 1.12 installation with a lot of categories. All categories are sorted descending, by changing the follow line in Toolbar.php:

```
public $_direction = 'desc';
```

Problem is my client want to change the direction of a single category to ascending. Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List/Toolbar.php` there's a function called `getCurrentDirection()` which is called in the `toolbar.phtml` template. We can rewrite and extend `Toolbar.php` and change this function in this way:

```
/**
 * Retrieve current direction
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getCurrentDirection()
{
    $dir = $this->_getData('_current_grid_direction');
    if ($dir) {
        return $dir;
    }

    $directions = array('asc', 'desc');
    $dir = strtolower($this->getRequest()->getParam($this->getDirectionVarName()));
    if ($dir && in_array($dir, $directions)) {
        if ($dir == $this->_direction) {
            Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->unsSortDirection();
        } else {
            $this->_memorizeParam('sort_direction', $dir);
        }
    } else {
        $dir = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->getSortDirection();
    }
    // validate direction
    if (!$dir || !in_array($dir, $directions)) {
        // Addition: get current category for custom direction
        $_category = Mage::registry('current_category');
        if ($_category && $_category->getId() == 10) {
            $dir = 'asc';
        } else {
            $dir = $this->_direction;
        }
    }
    $this->setData('_current_grid_direction', $dir);
    return $dir;
}
```

Note the addition of getting the current category, and testing for the category ID. (Replace '10' with whatever category ID you're using.)